# Turn off display for custom sidebar post widget when on the post it's displaying

Tags: posts, customization, css

Hope my title makes sense, I've attached a picture for what I mean.
I'm trying to use a simple bit of CSS.

```css
body.page-id-60748, .widget_its-single-post {
     display: none !important;
}
```

[image: post widget I don't want to display when on the actual page]

Comment: there's no way to solve this with just a screenshot, how is the widget implemented? Did you build the widget? 3rd party plugin/theme dev support questions are off topic here

Comment: It's a custom widget, I got it working in the end, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The post sidebar widget displays recent posts, including the one you're on. I wanted to disable the widgets that link to the one you're on. I.e. don't display current post in sidebar widget